# Eclipse Abstract Syntax Tree Programmatic Access

Tags: java, eclipse, abstract-syntax-tree

Could you provide an example of accessing the Eclipse Abstract Syntax Tree programmatically for a given piece of code?

eg getting the AST for:

---

### Class1.java

```
package parseable;

public class Class1 {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello world!");
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not an *exact* answer, that may give you a place where to start:

As said in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160382/extract-all-string-from-a-java-project#161145),

A full example is available in this [eclipse corner article](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-JavaCodeManipulation_AST/index.html), also more details in the [eclipse help](http://help.eclipse.org/help33/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/dom/ASTParser.html). And in the slide 59 of [this presentation](http://www1.cs.columbia.edu/~aho/cs4117/lectures/Static%20Analysis%20for%20Java%20in%20Eclipse.pdf), you see how to apply a change to your source code.

Answer (score 1):

```
// get an ICompilationUnit by some means
// you might drill down from an IJavaProject, for instance 
ICompilationUnit iunit = ...

// create a new parser for the latest Java Language Spec
ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS3);

// tell the parser you are going to pass it some code where the type level is a source file
// you might also just want to parse a block, or a method ("class body declaration"), etc
parser.setKind(ASTParser.K_COMPILATION_UNIT);

// set the source to be parsed to the ICompilationUnit
// we could also use a character array
parser.setSource(iunit);

// parse it.
// the output will be a CompilationUnit (also an ASTNode)
// the null is because we're not using a progress monitor
CompilationUnit unit = (CompilationUnit) parser.createAST(null);
```

Don't be confused by the ICompilationUnit vs CompilationUnit distinction, which seems to be just the result of uncreative naming on their part. CompilationUnit is a type of ASTNode. ICompilationUnit in this context resembles a file handle. For more info on the distinction, see here: http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_manipulate_Java_code%3F