# Find hardcoded Strings in legacy application

Tags: java, internationalization

I inherited a Java-Application with many *many* hardcoded Strings that should have been localized. THe code-base is huge and I need an overview about all the used hardcoded String values in the code. Is there a tool (or an IDE-function; I use Eclipse and IntelliJ IDEA) that extracts all strings from Java-classes?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160382/extract-all-string-from-a-java-project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Eclipse you can use the menu option Source > Externalize Strings...

This only works on a single file at a time however.

Answer (score 0):

I would recomend you to run your code through [SonarCube](http://www.sonarqube.org/). It's great tool that gives you a good overview the projects technical debt.