# Moving Objective-C hard-coded string literals to constants automatically

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macros, automated-refactoring, hardcoded

I have a project source code with like 100s of classes that liberally uses hard coded strings throughout the code.

```
NSArray *sql_stmt = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: DB_QUERY,
                   [[jsonDictionary objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"RECORD_ID"],
                   [[jsonDictionary objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"RECORD_LANGUAGE"],
                   [[jsonDictionary objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"INDEX_PATH"],
                   [[jsonDictionary objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"KEY"],
                   [[jsonDictionary objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"VALUE"],nil];
```

The requirement is to extract all such hardcoded string literals and move it to a class that holds all the constants.

```
#define RECORD_ID @"RECORD_ID"
#define RECORD_LANGUAGE @"RECORD_LANGUAGE"
```

etc

It will be too much effort to move all those 100s of strings manually from each class.

Is there a way we could automate this in XCode ? If there is no built in way to do it, I was wondering whether XCode supports writing a macro for this purpose.

Though I can quickly put together a Java or C# based GUI tool where I could paste the source code of one class at a time and get all the strings extracted and replaced by auto-generated name constants, I am hoping to find a solution without having to leave XCode.

Comment: You may take a look at the command line tools `grep`, `sed` and `awk`.

Comment: Thanks @CouchDeveloper. Surely we can ! We could use a tool/script/program that can find the strings that goes in the format @"mystring" and replace all of it with a constant name with a bit of simple logic applied to it in the naming. We could then even insert the original declaration in a specified declarations file as well. However, before developing such a solution, and probably sharing it to the community so that everyone can save time, I was wondering if there is someway that we could achieve this without user having to leave XCode. Like the code structuring and re-intending features.

Comment: I'm not aware of an integrated tool into Xcode that can specifically solve this problem. Xcode isn't particularly powerful when it comes to refactoring. However, even if this was a project in Visual Studio which is known for its strong refactoring capabilities, I would not try to solve it with it. Instead, grep, awk and sed are optimal for this very specific case.

Comment: Found the same question but about Java, and Eclipse has a solution : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160382/extract-all-string-from-a-java-project