# Xcode equivalent to IntelliJ's extract constant

Tags: xcode, refactoring, keyboard-shortcuts

In IntelliJ I can select some expression value and extract to a constant (amongst other options); is there an Xcode equivalent?

The only question I have found relating to my issue is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35188579/moving-objective-c-hard-coded-string-literals-to-constants-automatically),
and the solution is sub-optimal.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use AppCode instead. It's made by the same folks who make IntelliJ, but is for Swift/Obj-C development.

Comment: That is certainly an option.  Last time I looked at AppCode you still needed Xcode for the IB, not sure I like the idea of working on a project in two IDEs far too much potential for file corruption.

Comment: AppCode actively does two things to stay in sync: saves immediately, and reloads any files that were changed by another tool